# Swift: tableView always "found nil while unwr..." inside a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a `viewController` I've connected a `tableView outlet` in the SB with delegates and datasource set and when I'm accessing the reference outlet in code it always crashes with the message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet var resultTabView: UITableView!
```

Connection:

[image]

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` -
I'm not even using resultsArray, though the array is returning data as seen in the logs

**EDIT 2:**

Data:

```
id = 2325;    
results =     (
                    {
                city = Delhi;
                company = "AIR CREATOR";
                country = IN;
                date = "Mon, 11 Jul 2016 04:51:34 GMT";
                expired = 0;
                formattedLocation = "Delhi, Delhi";
                formattedLocationFull = "Delhi, Delhi";
                formattedRelativeTime = "30+ days ago";
                jobkey = 67ba422cc328a946;
                jobtitle = "CSA for airport";
                latitude = "28.664835";
                longitude = "77.21429000000001";
                onmousedown = "indeed_clk(this,'3586');";
                snippet = "Providing boarding passes and luggage <b>labels</b>. Your daily tasks will usually include:....";
                source = Indeed;
                sponsored = 0;
                state = DL;
                url = "http://www.indeed.co.in/viewjob?jk=67ba422cc328a946&qd=SHSUhPNSBYpqaNu9AVdfqv81wDpAwFE36uyNVXcxl8VAUThqIJkZA1l3w1yQl8AJg05AJq_aODrwRlOUKXT92UBk4SDqDqM7LhTReglYsV0&indpubnum=4148406673078092&atk=1aqbfaj6kb958c17";
            },
                    {
                city = Delhi;
                company = "Letmedrive India Private Limited";
                country = IN;
                date = "Wed, 10 Aug 2016 13:02:51 GMT";
                expired = 0;
                formattedLocation = "Delhi, Delhi";
                formattedLocationFull = "Delhi, Delhi";
                formattedRelativeTime = "6 days ago";
                jobkey = 89c4f63f1b841720;
                jobtitle = "Graphics Designer";
                latitude = "28.664835";
                longitude = "77.21429000000001";
                onmousedown = "indeed_clk(this,'3586');";
                snippet = "Graphic designers/artists design graphics for use in media products such as magazines, <b>labels</b> &amp; advertising....";
                source = Indeed;
                sponsored = 0;
                state = DL;
                url = "http://www.indeed.co.in/viewjob?jk=89c4f63f1b841720&qd=SHSUhPNSBYpqaNu9AVdfqv81wDpAwFE36uyNVXcxl8VAUThqIJkZA1l3w1yQl8AJg05AJq_aODrwRlOUKXT92UBk4SDqDqM7LhTReglYsV0&indpubnum=4148406673078092&atk=1aqbfaj6kb958c17";
            };
```

**Class:**

```
class JobListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet var searchField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var resultTabView: UITableView!

var resultsArray = [JSON]()
var resultsDictionary = [String:String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func focusSearchField(search:Bool, keyword:String){
    if(search){
        callAPI(keyword)
    }else{
        searchField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func callAPI(keyword:String){
    var params = [String:String]()
    params["publisher"] = "2341411"
    params["q"] = keyword
    params["l"] = "dubai"
    params["latlong"] = "1"
    params["v"] = "2"
    params["format"] = "json"
    params["co"] = "uae"
    let svcMgr = ServiceManager()
    svcMgr.httpRequest(self, params: params)
}

func updateUI(result: [String:AnyObject]){
    if let val = result["results"] {
        let json = JSON(val)
        let array = json.arrayValue

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            for a in array{
                self.resultsArray.append(a)
            }
            self.resultTabView.reloadData()
        })
    }else{

    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return resultsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JobCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            let labl2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
            labl2.text = (resultsArray[indexPath.row]["jobtitle"].stringValue)+" @"+(resultsArray[indexPath.row]["source"].stringValue)
            let labl3 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
            labl3.text = (resultsArray[indexPath.row]["state"].stringValue)+", "+(resultsArray[indexPath.row]["country"].stringValue)
            let labl4 = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
            labl4.text = (resultsArray[indexPath.row]["snippet"].stringValue)+" "
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: resultsArray[indexPath.row]["url"].stringValue)!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - TextField delegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    callAPI(textField.text!)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Check the resultTabView  datasource and delegates connection

Comment: see that in the attached image

Comment: the crash might not in the tableView, but the data, try go print the `resultTabView ` before `reloadData` and see if its nil or not

Comment: May be you are getting crash in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for you json response, check properly.

Comment: resutlTabView is nil even before reloadingData, what might be wrong here?

Comment: @AtifImran crash is because of data which you are trying to set in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Check one of your value is optional, You should not assign `nil` value to any control. Put you code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as well as JSON response here.

Comment: enable breakpint and check once insie the `cellForRowAtIndexPa‌th`

Comment: Plase check array is empty or not

Comment: See EDIT: no it's not see logs, I'm not even using it, the crash is for some other reason

Comment: can you attach your project here we will check

Comment: I think the problem is in resultsArray = (val as? [AnyObject])! this line you are getting nil value here and you are trying to unwrapped it so try to type cast in proper object not AnyObject.

Comment: Try to add an "All Exception" breakpoint from "Add Exception breakpoint..." and now run the app again you will be stopped in exact line where the optional error you are encountering & please submit those lines may be from there any one of us should get a solution.

Comment: @AtifImran Try to show all code of view controller. Have you registered view controller to `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` these delegates?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps,

1. Please remove all connection with table view and add that again.
2. Make sure tableViewCellIdentifier have same name set in storyboard as given in code.
3. remove "!" mark after AnyObject, i beleive you need this

   var  resultsArray = (val as? [AnyObject])
4. This is not table view reloading error, its parsing issue. Please check all your declare properties.If possible show all your table view data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `viewDidLoad` method is called before attempting to access the table view. Your connection from XIB is probably not established by the time this code runs.

Comment: Isn't it the first thing that gets called when loading a view controller?

Comment: What do you mean by _“loading a view controller”_? Allocating it? No. The XIB is loaded with IBOutlet connections the first time you access `.view` property. Accessing any other IBOutlet property will not load the XIB.

Comment: You can see my edited question which shows the whole class now

Comment: @AtifImran I don’t want to see more of your code. I want you to put a breakpoint to `viewDidLoad` and on `.reloadData()` lines and see which one is called first. Also, find where is `updateUI()` called from, because that’s also a relevant part.