# What wrong with json data parsing?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I've tried to parse data using `resultsArray = [AnyObject]()` as well as `resultsArray = [JSON]()` both give me crashes

My data:

```
data = (
      {
      id = 2141
      results =  (
                {
                city = Delhi;
                company = "AIR CREATOR";
                country = IN;
                },
                {
                city = Dubai;
                company = "Alwali";
                country = UAE;
                }
        );
    })
```

Now, when I parse I get crash at `reloadData`:

```
if let val = data["results"] {
            let json = JSON(val)
            let array = json.arrayValue

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                for a in array{
                    self.resultsArray.append(a)
                }
                self.myTableView.reloadData()//<--crash point
            })
        }
```

**When I print**

```
print(self.resultsArray[0])
```

> {   "city" : "Delhi",   "country" : "IN",   "company" : "AIR CREATOR"
>   }

```
print(self.resultsArray[0]["country"])
```

> IN

Comment: try to print total resultsArray.

Comment: Check your IBOutlet of `tableVIew` is connected?

Comment: all connected and checked. Pulling my hair out

Comment: What printed on console when it crashed ?

Comment: check whether `self` or `myTableView` are not `nil`.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988426/swift-tableview-always-found-nil-while-unwr-inside-a-viewcontroller this is the related question

Comment: Where is myTableView() defined? Is it out of scope?

Comment: As an iboutlet coonected in SB

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant code and complete error message. Your code doesn't seem to be related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
if let array = data["results"] {
  // var resultsArray: [[String: String]] = [] // your property should be like this
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    for a in array {
      self.resultsArray.append(a)
    }
    print(resultsArray)
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
  })
}
```

Comment: not the type mismatch resultsArray can't store a JSON this way

Comment: Isn't it an array? In my code it is an array of JSON.

Comment: Dont you want your array to store like { "city" : "Delhi", "country" : "IN", "company" : "AIR CREATOR" }s

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a breakpoint before reloadData and in your debug area after (lldb) write: (each line as a separate command)

```
po self.myTableView
po self.myTableView.delegate 
po self.myTableView.dataSource
```

check the outputs for any nil value.

Edit:
One more thing, I faced the same issue before and the reason was a problem in my custom cell , there was a problem with the connection of one of the cell outlets, check for exclamation marks in the connection inspector tap in storyboard.